# How to generate an ipa with expo (react native) for production?

Tags: react-native, build, expo, ipa, organization

i work for a key account and i'm a beginner in react native. I work on a PC and i use expo when i want to build an ipa for iOS . It's very easy for a development version but i'm stucked when i build for production.
I have the following error :
validateProvisioningProfile: provisioning profile is not associated with uploaded distribution certificate
The message seems very clear but it's not.
Actually, i've a dev account and i have to use a distribution profile from my organisation. My dev account is part of my organisation and i thought it was enough to pass the test but it's not. Help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get `Mac` (not PC), open apple developer account and run in the project folder:

```
expo build:ios
```

you will get a url with an option to download `ipa` file

Comment: Hi Idan, thanks for your answer. I've no problem to build from a pc because when you execute this command line "expo build:ios" => it builds on an expo machine (which is a mac); My problem is slightly different, i want to build with a provisioning profile (set just after expo build:ios) which associated dev account is different than mine. I work in a key account and the provisioning profile is provided but the right dev account not. When you build on xcode, there is no control between the provisioning profile and the apple dev account but i hae to build with expo.